# How to avoid that Visual Studio incremental build does not run when files outside <Compile> and <EmbeddedResource> are changed?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, incremental-build

I have a VS2017 csharp project and the .csproj file looks like the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
        <MyItem Include="file.dat" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
            $(PrepareResourcesDependsOn);
            MyCompileTarget
         </PrepareResourcesDependsOn>
        <CoreCompileDependsOn>
            $(CoreCompileDependsOn);
            MyCompileTarget
        </CoreCompileDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="MyCompileTarget" Inputs="@(MyItem)" Outputs="@(MyItem->'%(FileName).out')">
    ...
    </Target>
 </Project>
```

Where `MyCompileTarget` is a target that generates the `file.out` from `file.dat` (in the actual code the incremental build target and properties are in a target file automatically included via a NuGet package).

The issue is that if I change `file.dat` and press on **Build**, **no** target is executed **at all**, (but `MyTarget` is correctly executed with **Rebuild** or when running with msbuild). I would expect the `MyCompileTarget` to be executed so that the `file.out` file is updated.

The same issue occurs if I use `BeforeBuild` or `AfterBuild` instead of `PrepareResourcesDependsOn` etc.

It seems that Visual Studio incremental build won't start unless some file in `@(Compile)` or `@(EmbeddedResource)` is changed. Indeed, if I add the following

```
<EmbeddedResource>file.dat</EmbeddedResource>
```

the incremental build works as expected (but clearly I do not want to embeed the `file.dat` into the generated assembly).

Is it possible to force Visual Studio to enable incremental build if `file.dat` is modified, and if the corresponding generated file is older than `file.dat` or it does not exist?

Note: the same issue occurs using VS2015, with .NET CORE or .NET FRAMEWORK.
Also, incremental build will be triggered if I change a csharp file, and it will therefore trigger `MyTask`, but only if `file.dat` is newer than the generated file (as expected).

Thanks in advance,
Fabio.

Comment: If you run this with verbose output, does it say why the target gets skipped? What might help is adding a record to the file tracker mechanism in your target, something like `<WriteLinesToFile File="$(TLogLocation)$(ProjectName).write.u.tlog" Lines="@(MyItem->'%(FileName).out"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but still didn't work. When I change the source file it still won't recompile, unless I delete the output file. Is there a way to instert the file in some list so that the 'fast-up-to-date' in Visual Studio will catch the change (difference between source and output file)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to force Visual Studio to enable incremental build if file.dat is modified

You can set the property `DisableFastUpToDateCheck` to `true` in the project file to disable `FastUpToDateCheck` for Visual Studio build manager:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Check [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties) about DisableFastUpToDateCheck:

> A boolean value that applies to Visual Studio only. **The Visual Studio
>   build manager uses a process called FastUpToDateCheck to determine
>   whether a project must be rebuilt to be up to date.** This process is
>   faster than using MSBuild to determine this. **Setting the
>   DisableFastUpToDateCheck property to true lets you bypass the Visual
>   Studio build manager and force it to use MSBuild to determine whether
>   the project is up to date**

Update:

Also, we can set the `UpToDateCheckInput` to the item:

```
<UpToDateCheckInput Include="file.dat" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply :)
Is there a way to do that without disabling the fast-up-to-date-check?

I tried this `<UpToDateCheckInput Include="file.dat" />` but it won't work.

Comment: The issue is that I need to keep fast up to date checks enabled for performance reasons, and the solution above (UpToDateCheckInput) won't work, at least not when the item is in a .target file, which is automatically included in VS2017 projects via NuGet package reference.

Comment: @FabioStrocco, Not sure I understand you clear. You should add `<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>True</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>`  in the .csproj file under the line `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>` not in the .target file in the nuget package. Besides, if you want keep build performance and the file could not be set file in `@(Compile)` or `@(EmbeddedResource)`, I am afraid there is no  better way to solve this problem.

Comment: My fault, I placed the item group in the wrong place.
`<UpToDateCheckInput Include="file.dat" />` solves the issue while still keeping fast-up-to-date-check enabled, so I suggest you include it in your answer so I can close the topic.

Comment: What I am saying is that it seems to work when I add the following under `ItemGroup`: `<UpToDateCheckInput Include="file.dat" />`, even whith fast-track-update-check set to true.
Apparently it will now include file.dat in the fast-up-to-date checks, therefore triggering the build when file.dat changes (it will then be my build script that decides which targets to run).
Does it make sense to you? I found this post below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026355/how-to-avoid-that-visual-studio-incremental-build-does-not-run-when-files-outsid?noredirect=1#comment87072582_50026355

Comment: The reason why I want to place all this into a NuGet target file is that I want to distribute a compiler as a NuGet package, which will automatically trigger compilation on build, without the NuGet package user has to include anything else than `MyItem` in its .csproj file.

Comment: You should never have to disable the up to date check. This is bad advice, and I suggest deleting or editing this answer. People will copy/paste that property to their projects and suffer through slow builds.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the VS fast up-to-date check will make your builds much slower. Don't do it!

Instead, make sure the up-to-date check knows about the items in your project and how they relate to build. There are two kinds of item you can add to your project for this:

- `UpToDateCheckInput` for inputs
- `UpToDateCheckBuilt` for outputs

In your case you need the second option as there is both an input and an output. You need to ensure that if you delete the output, it is rebuilt.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <UpToDateCheckBuilt Original="@(MyItem)" Include="@(MyItem->'%(FileName).out')">
</ItemGroup>
```

For more information, see the documentation:

https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/up-to-date-check.md

Comment: UpToDateCheckBuilt is not a property. Should this be in an ItemGroup maybe?