Compiling GLSL shaders in Visual Studio
I managed to make a working setup in Visual Studio 2022 to automate compilation of GLSL shaders, but it looks like a total mess. So, I am wondering if there is better, more clean approach to achieve the same.
So far, I have it like this:
MainProj
ShaderCompiler (this is a small program that checks timestamp of source and binary files and if binaries are out-of-date it recompiles that out-of-date binaries)
Shaders ( this project keeps all shader sources for the entire solution )
The Shaders project depends on the ShaderCompiler and MainProj depends on the Shaders.
Also, Shaders has a custom .targets file it depends on:
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Include definitions from VulkanGLSLShaderCompiler.xml, which defines the VulkanGLSLShader item. -->
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)VulkanGLSLShaderCompiler.xaml" />
    <!-- Hook up VulkanGLSLShader items to be built by the VulkanGLSLShaderCompiler target. -->
    <AvailableItemName Include="VulkanGLSLShader">
      <Targets>VulkanGLSLShaderCompiler</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
        <BinShaderOutPath Include="$(OutDir)shaders"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="EnsureShaderOutputDirectoryExists">
        <MakeDir Directories="@(BinShaderOutPath)" />
    </Target>

    
  <Target
    Name="VulkanGLSLShaderCompiler"
    Condition="'@(VulkanGLSLShader)' != ''"
    BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
    DependsOnTargets="EnsureShaderOutputDirectoryExists">
    
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Building shaders!!!" />

    <!-- Setup metadata for custom build tool -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <VulkanGLSLShader>
        <Command>
            "$(SolutionDir)_tools\ShaderCompiler" "%(FullPath)" "$(OutDir)shaders\%(Filename)%(Extension).spv"
        </Command>
        <Outputs>$(OutDir)shaders\%(Filename)%(Extension).spv</Outputs>
      </VulkanGLSLShader>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Compile by forwarding to the Custom Build Tool infrastructure,
         so it will take care of .tlogs and error/warning parsing -->
    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(VulkanGLSLShader)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="true"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(TLogLocation)"
      ErrorListRegex="(?'FILENAME'.+):(?'LINE'\d+):(?'COLUMN'\d+): (?'CATEGORY'error|warning): (?'TEXT'.*)" />
  </Target>
</Project>

This is the only approach that lets me compile shaders automatically and only those shaders whose binaries our out of date (or do not exist). The other approaches I tried, at best, compile all the shader sources even if I don't touch shader files at all, i.e. I change smth inside  .cpp/.hpp files, MSBuild thinks it's right thing to compile shaders.
I don't like this approach either, I believe if my entire solution is going to evolve it may end up having a number of projects which have their own shaders, so it would be more logical to put shaders in the respective projects, rather than having on project with all the shaders for the solution.
So, I wonder if someone have a working .targets file for VS 2022 that invokes compilation of only those shader source files whos binaries are out of date or do not exist.

An already made .targets I don't have but you could use UpToDateCheckInput / UpToDateCheckBuilt items https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026355/how-to-avoid-that-visual-studio-incremental-build-does-not-run-when-files-outsid
